# call variable from models.py from django template

Tags: html, django, variables

My code so far is:

```
            <div class="icon-and-title-flex">
                <img src="static/img/profile.png" class="appicon"></img>
                <div class="title-container">
                    <!-- REPLACE WITH YOUR APP NAME -->
                    <span class="text-title">Dashboard</span>
                    <br><div class="intertext-padding"></div>
                    <!-- REPLACE WITH YOUR DEV NAME -->
                    <span class="text-subtitle">by Student Accounts</span>
                    <br><div class="intertext-padding"></div>
                    <!-- REPLACE WITH YOUR APP PRICE -->
                    <span class="text-subtitle">{{ user.first_name }}</span>
                </div>
```

Where i have {{ user.first_name }}, i want to call a variable from my models.py and display it there. What's the correct syntax for this? (This doesn't seem to work. )

EDIT:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
    from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
    from django.conf.urls import url
    from .models import UserInfo, Events
    from django import forms
    from .forms import RegisterForm, LoginForm, OrderForm
    from django.contrib.auth.models import User
    from django.shortcuts import redirect
    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
    # Create your views here.

    def home(request):
        return render(request, 'student/index.html')

    @csrf_exempt
    def signin(request):
        print "login"
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            username = request.POST['username']
            password = request.POST['password']
            print "input username ", username
            try:
                if form.is_valid():
                    user = authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                    if user is not None:
                        print "user not none"
                        print user.username
                        print user.email
                        login(request,user)
                        return redirect("/")
                    else:
                        print "login failed"
                        raise forms.ValidationError({'username':['Invalid username/password']})
                else:
                    print form.errors
            except:
                raise


        else:
            print "hello"
            form = LoginForm()

        return render(request, 'student/login.html', {'form': form})

    @csrf_exempt
    def signup(request):
        print "signup"
        if request.method == 'POST':
            print "post signup"
            form = RegisterForm(request.POST)
            try:
                if form.is_valid():
                    print form.cleaned_data
                    u = User.objects.create_user(form.cleaned_data['emailid'], form.cleaned_data['emailid'], form.cleaned_data['passwd1'] )

                    ui = UserInfo()
                    ui.user = u
                    ui.class_of = form.cleaned_data['gradyear']
                    ui.grade = form.cleaned_data['grade']
                    ui.balance = 0

                    ui.save()
                    user = authenticate(username=form.cleaned_data['emailid'], password=form.cleaned_data['passwd1'])
                    login(request,user)
                    print "after login in signup"
                    return redirect("/")


                else:
                    print "error"
                    print form.errors
            except:
                raise
                print "error here"
                print form.errors
                pass
                #return render(request, 'student/register.html', {'form': form})

        else:
            form = RegisterForm()

        return render(request, 'student/register.html', {'form': form})

    def forgotpassword(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = LoginForm(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                # process the data in form.cleaned_data as required
                # ...
                # redirect to a new URL:

                print form.cleaned_data
                return HttpResponseRedirect('/thanks/')
            else:
                print "INVALID"
                print form.errors
        else:
             form = LoginForm()
        return render(request, 'student/forgotpassword.html')


    def studentinfo(request):
        return render(request, 'student/studentinfo.html', {} )

    def error(request):
        return render(request, 'student/LoginError.html', {} )

    def site_logout(request):
        logout(request)
        return redirect("/")
        #return render(request, 'student/studentinfo.html', {} )

    def order(request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form = 0
        return render(request, 'student/orderform.html')

    def dashboard(request):
            return render(request, 'student/dashboard.html')
```

This is my view.py, I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: This seems to be right syntax. Maybe there is no variable 'user' in your context or first_name property is empty.

Comment: Show your view. Are you passing an object called `user` into the template context?

Comment: Or maybe you don't have appropriate context processor enabled?

Comment: you're not passing any user object to template

Comment: Now you've posted too much code. Which of those views is the one responsible for rendering this template?

Comment: @DanielRoseman dashboard. should i be passing an object to it?

Answer (score 0):

Your template is using `{{ user.first_name }}`, but your `dashboard` method in views.py is not passing any `user` object to the template, thus your template wouldn't show any user. It sounds like you want to get current user's information, so your view should be:

```
def dashboard(request):
    user = request.user
    return render(request, 'student/dashboard.html', {'user': user})
```

You need to understand why you need to pass a variable from the view method in order to use it, the [doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/intro/tutorial03/#a-shortcut-render) is here.

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, works the same as before. My user.username, user.password and user.email variables show up, but not the user.first_name or user.last_name (this was also happening before i added your code) @ShangWang

Comment: You didn't mention that `user.username` and `user.password` are showing up fine. Are you using the default `User` model that django provides? If so can you check to see if the `user.first_name` and `user.last_name` are non-empty?